# My site does not reroute after uploading to server

Tags: angularjs, hosting

I wrote a angular site, and in it I use rerouting to get a partial view into the main index. My site works fine when it's on my local PC.

The main view, **Index.html**, has a `ng-view` div, which should display The partial view in **Chapter.html** when the site first loads. The code for this is in **myScript**, `app.Config`.

I uploaded the site to Somee hosting server, and the **Chapter.html** view is not shown inside **index.html**.
I researched a bit and it seems that servers shouldn't have problems with angularjs. Besides, it doesn't seem to be a problem with **all** of angular, because my `banner` directive works.

I'm using my own copies of angular script, but I don't think that's the issue.

This is the basics of my code:

**Index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="he" dir="rtl">
<head>
    <link href="../css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/MyStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="../modules/myModule.js"></script>
    <script src="../Controllers/myController.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/MyScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" class="container-fluid"> 
    <banner></banner>
    <div id="chapter" class="ng-view">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Chapter.html:**

```
<div>
    <img src="../Images/Chapter1.1.jpg" />
</div>
```

**myScript.js:**

```
app.directive("banner", function () {
    return {
        template: "<h1>My Title</h1>"
    };
});


app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "Chapter.html"
    });
});
```

Comment: "*the partial view is not shown*" is too broad

Comment: @Amit, how can I make it less broad? I think my question is actually very specific, but I haven't doing a good job of explaining it, since I'm realy new in angular.

Comment: Start by isolating the problem. What is the first step that fails?

Comment: I faced a similar problem long ago. The scenario was that on my local machine the file name was case-insensitive. If I had a file named `chapter.html` and I used it as `Chapter.html`, it worked fine on local machine; but wasn't working on server. So just check that the case of your actual file and wherever you're using them is all the same.

Comment: @RamanSahasi, good point, but my local PC is case sensitive as well, so all the names **are** precise.

Comment: Use browser dev tools network to check status of all requests